# Create a script to print out text before a : character, each output in a separate line

Tags: bash

I have a file with hostnames and ips, I want to print out each hostname and ip in a separate line. I am working on Linux host with bash and I have a : as a delimiter but there can be spaces before and after the : in some of the output.

My file looks like:

hostname.abc.com :10.10.1.1:hostname2.abc.com:10.12.40.1 hostname5.abc.com :hostname3.abc.com:hostname4.abc.com:10.12.40.1 hostname6.abc.com :10.10.5.8:hostname7.abc.com:10.12.41.1 hostname9.abc.com :10.10.1.6:hostname8.abc.com:10.12.2.1

There are about 50 lines, but some lines have up to 300 hostnames/ips.

I want the output to be a sequential file where there is a single hostname or ip per line.

I am trying something like:
awk 'f{print;f=0}/:/{f=1}' /home/aaro/parsedata/nfs6 |xargs -n1

But need to figure out how to iterate through each instance of the hostname on a line and iterate through the print.

My hostname does not begin with h all the time.
I can have up to 200 hostname and/or ips on the same line, I need to separate each one and print out one hostname or ip at a time.

I have a delimiter : but I don't know how to user the print command to print $1 through $200, each output on a separate line.

The hostnames and ips differs from my shared file, as it would not be a good idea to share hostnames and ips.

I can't put it my desired output. I need each column with either a hostname or an ip on a separate line, but the editor here bunches the output into one line even though I put a separate line for each hostname and ip.

Each column with a : delimiter in a separate line, each line has different numbers of columns, some have 1, some 6 some, 5 some 187 and some 200 columns.

Comment: Can you provide the script you have made already?

Comment: And how should the output look like? And why didn't `cut -d: -f1` worked?

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Cut only prints the first column, I want to print every column in a line, each line differs, one line could have 1 column, the other 6 columns, and several have 200 columns.

Answer (score 0):

First remove some spaces for an easier `grep` command

```
sed 's/[ ]*:[ ]*/:/g' file | grep -Eo "[a-zA-Z][^:]*:[0-9.]*"
```

or

```
sed 's/[ ]*:[ ]*/:/g' file | grep -Eo "[^:]+:[0-9.]*"
```

EDIT: First I used an `h` for finding the first letter of the hostname.

Comment: Thank you Walter, but this assumes I have an h at the beginning of each hostname which is not the case. I am trying to parse the output from columns to a separate field in each line. So if I have three columns hostname1:hostname2:hostname3 I want each of the hostnames to show up on a separate line. Of course the hostname will vary but there is a separator :.

Comment: Hi Ana, I modified the answer. Look at your example input, I am missing a separator between `10.12.40.1` and `hostname5`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the output to be a sequential file where there is a single hostname or ip per line, then this sed is enough :

```
sed 'y/:/\n/' infile
```